# ASP.NET MVC Ajax - AjaxOptions.HttpMethod default is GET, not POST - wrong docs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msdn

When calling `Ajax.ActionLink` and passing a new instance of AjaxOptions, HttpMethod is by default GET, **not** POST as stated by the documentation. Is the documentation wrong or does `ActionLink` modify the `AjaxOptions` structure somehow by checking whether the property had been set by the user? I don't see why it would.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.httpmethod.aspx

Comment: Comunity content on the link you provided says that GET is the default option also. I would call it an error in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the default is actually empty string (according to Reflector) and the classes that use it treat `""` as GET. So the default is GET, the docs are wrong.

Comment: Source code: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Ajax/AjaxOptions.cs